# How do i make a welcoming command in discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

Im trying to make a welcome message for my bot but the message never works. I have all 3 intents enabled and i dont know whats wrong. Can someone please help?

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = bot.get_channel(906928559602421830)
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Welcome!",description=f"{member.mention} Just Joined")
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Are you receiving any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

What does the alfred stands for?

And for the code:

```
@bot.event
 async def on_member_join(member):
  guild = member.guild
  channel = guild.get_channel(channel_id)

  embed=discord.Embed(title="Welcome!",description=f"{member.mention} Just Joined")
  await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: The alfred part was a mistake in my message. Sorry about that lol